# Tab Width CSS not working in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I have the following css for tabs,

```
.columbia-browser-blackberry .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .columbia-browser-  
chrome .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .columbia-browser-iemobile .ui-tabs .ui-
tabs-nav li a, .columbia-browser-safari .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, 
.columbia-browser-moz.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a
{
    padding: .5em 1em;
    width: 225px;
    word-wrap: initial;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

Html

```
/**
* Page Tabs Control
* @TODO guerrics: overflowing tabs
*
* @param array pages - array of pages (default: map.values(page.subpages))
* @param str tab - name of the selected tab (default: __request.args.tab)
*/
var pages = $pages ?? map.values(page.subpages);
let pages = [ (p is str) ? wiki.getpage(p) : p foreach var p in pages];
var selectedTab = $tab ?? __request.args.tab;

// find the active tab page
var activeTab = [ tabpage foreach var tabpage in pages where tabpage.name ==      
selectedTab ][0];

// no selected tab found, use first tab
if (!activeTab) {
let activeTab = pages[0];
}
<div class="mt-tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"    
id="tabs">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-  
header ui-corner-all">
        foreach(var tabpage in pages) {
            <li id=('tab-'..tabpage.name) class=('ui-state-default ui-
corner-top'..(tabpage.name == activeTab.name ? " ui-tabs-selected ui-state-
active " : ""))>
                <a href=(page.uri & {tab: tabpage.name})>
                    tabpage.title ?? "#" .. (__count + 1)
                </a><span></span>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <div class=("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"..(#pages 
 > 0 ? "" : "ui-state-empty"))>
        if (activeTab) {
            var contents = activeTab.contents;
            if (contents) {
                contents;
            } else {
                wiki.page(activeTab.path);
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

It works for Google chrome, but it doesn't work in Mozilla and Internet Explorer. I am trying to giving the tabs a uniform width of 225px.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: try width:225px !important. if it not works please give your full code.

Comment: here required inline-block to set width and height `display:inline-block`

Comment: There is no specifics code for tabs. The tabs are called through a template. Whatever topics that i create in the wiki are then displayed as tabs. I have added the code above.

Comment: width:225px !important did not work @Sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it worked.

```
  body .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a 
  {
   padding: .5em 1em;
   width:225px;
   word-wrap: initial;
   height: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**To apply width, set css property 'display' to either 'block' or 'inline-block'.**

block: the element will sit in a single line. In such case you may want to set float so links are in the same line;

inline-block; the element will have height, width, etc, and multiple elements will sit in the same line (block).

try with:

```
display:inline-block
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, This didn't work. The css is working fine with Chrome but not for Mozilla and IE.

Comment: fine, but you should set `display:inline-block` instead of `display:inline`, if you work with width, height, padding, etc

Comment: Ok..i will surely use it. Thanks for the tip Rohit!!